# How to use Dynamic Feature module with BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

Adding dynamic feature using a navigation graph like the one below and works fine with viewPager2, or another fragment, but not with a `BottomNavigationView`.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</layout>
```

Nav graph for a tab of `BottomNavigationView` that should navigate to dynamic feature module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_dashboard"
    app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment1">

    ...

    <!-- photos dynamic feature module-->
    <include-dynamic
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_photos"
        android:name="com.abc.photos"
        app:graphResName="nav_graph_photos"
        app:moduleName="photos">
        <argument
            android:name="count"
            android:defaultValue="0"
            app:argType="integer" />
    </include-dynamic>

</navigation>
```

Since `BottomNavigationView` has no individual back stack for fragments for it's tabs and this class is used for back navigation.

```
/**
 * Manages the various graphs needed for a [BottomNavigationView].
 *
 * This sample is a workaround until the Navigation Component supports multiple back stacks.
 */
fun BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
    navGraphIds: List<Int>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    containerId: Int,
    intent: Intent
): LiveData<NavController> {

    // Map of tags
    val graphIdToTagMap = SparseArray<String>()
    // Result. Mutable live data with the selected controlled
    val selectedNavController = MutableLiveData<NavController>()

    var firstFragmentGraphId = 0

    // First create a NavHostFragment for each NavGraph ID
    navGraphIds.forEachIndexed { index, navGraphId ->
        val fragmentTag = getFragmentTag(index)

        // Find or create the Navigation host fragment
        val navHostFragment = obtainNavHostFragment(
            fragmentManager,
            fragmentTag,
            navGraphId,
            containerId
        )

        // Obtain its id
        val graphId = navHostFragment.navController.graph.id

        if (index == 0) {
            firstFragmentGraphId = graphId
        }

        // Save to the map
        graphIdToTagMap[graphId] = fragmentTag

        // Attach or detach nav host fragment depending on whether it's the selected item.
        if (this.selectedItemId == graphId) {
            // Update livedata with the selected graph
            selectedNavController.value = navHostFragment.navController
            attachNavHostFragment(fragmentManager, navHostFragment, index == 0)
        } else {
            detachNavHostFragment(fragmentManager, navHostFragment)
        }
    }

    // Now connect selecting an item with swapping Fragments
    var selectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[this.selectedItemId]
    val firstFragmentTag = graphIdToTagMap[firstFragmentGraphId]
    var isOnFirstFragment = selectedItemTag == firstFragmentTag

    // When a navigation item is selected
    setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        // Don't do anything if the state is state has already been saved.
        if (fragmentManager.isStateSaved) {
            false
        } else {
            val newlySelectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[item.itemId]
            if (selectedItemTag != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                // Pop everything above the first fragment (the "fixed start destination")
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(
                    firstFragmentTag,
                    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
                )
                val selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag)
                        as NavHostFragment

                // Exclude the first fragment tag because it's always in the back stack.
                if (firstFragmentTag != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                    // Commit a transaction that cleans the back stack and adds the first fragment
                    // to it, creating the fixed started destination.
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .attach(selectedFragment)
                        .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(selectedFragment)
                        .apply {
                            // Detach all other Fragments
                            graphIdToTagMap.forEach { _, fragmentTagIter ->
                                if (fragmentTagIter != newlySelectedItemTag) {
                                    detach(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(firstFragmentTag)!!)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .addToBackStack(firstFragmentTag)
                        .setCustomAnimations(
                            R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim,
                            R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim
                        )
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .commit()
                }
                selectedItemTag = newlySelectedItemTag
                isOnFirstFragment = selectedItemTag == firstFragmentTag
                selectedNavController.value = selectedFragment.navController
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
    }

    // Optional: on item reselected, pop back stack to the destination of the graph
    setupItemReselected(graphIdToTagMap, fragmentManager)

    // Handle deep link
    setupDeepLinks(navGraphIds, fragmentManager, containerId, intent)

    // Finally, ensure that we update our BottomNavigationView when the back stack changes
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        if (!isOnFirstFragment && !fragmentManager.isOnBackStack(firstFragmentTag)) {
            this.selectedItemId = firstFragmentGraphId
        }

        // Reset the graph if the currentDestination is not valid (happens when the back
        // stack is popped after using the back button).
        selectedNavController.value?.let { controller ->
            if (controller.currentDestination == null) {
                controller.navigate(controller.graph.id)
            }
        }
    }
    return selectedNavController
}

private fun BottomNavigationView.setupDeepLinks(
    navGraphIds: List<Int>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    containerId: Int,
    intent: Intent
) {
    navGraphIds.forEachIndexed { index, navGraphId ->
        val fragmentTag = getFragmentTag(index)

        // Find or create the Navigation host fragment
        val navHostFragment = obtainNavHostFragment(
            fragmentManager,
            fragmentTag,
            navGraphId,
            containerId
        )
        // Handle Intent
        if (navHostFragment.navController.handleDeepLink(intent)
            && selectedItemId != navHostFragment.navController.graph.id
        ) {
            this.selectedItemId = navHostFragment.navController.graph.id
        }
    }
}

private fun BottomNavigationView.setupItemReselected(
    graphIdToTagMap: SparseArray<String>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) {
    setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { item ->
        val newlySelectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[item.itemId]
        val selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag)
                as NavHostFragment
        val navController = selectedFragment.navController
        // Pop the back stack to the start destination of the current navController graph
        navController.popBackStack(
            navController.graph.startDestination, false
        )
    }
}

private fun detachNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    navHostFragment: NavHostFragment
) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .detach(navHostFragment)
        .commitNow()
}

private fun attachNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    navHostFragment: NavHostFragment,
    isPrimaryNavFragment: Boolean
) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .attach(navHostFragment)
        .apply {
            if (isPrimaryNavFragment) {
                setPrimaryNavigationFragment(navHostFragment)
            }
        }
        .commitNow()

}

private fun obtainNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    fragmentTag: String,
    navGraphId: Int,
    containerId: Int
): NavHostFragment {
    // If the Nav Host fragment exists, return it
    val existingFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) as NavHostFragment?
    existingFragment?.let { return it }

    // Otherwise, create it and return it.
    val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.create(navGraphId)
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(containerId, navHostFragment, fragmentTag)
        .commitNow()
    return navHostFragment
}

private fun FragmentManager.isOnBackStack(backStackName: String): Boolean {
    val backStackCount = backStackEntryCount
    for (index in 0 until backStackCount) {
        if (getBackStackEntryAt(index).name == backStackName) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

private fun getFragmentTag(index: Int) = "bottomNavigation#$index"
```

When you add dynamic feature to any nav_graph this `BottomNavigationView` `setUpWithNavContoller` method using snippet below

```
   val navGraphIds = listOf(
        R.navigation.nav_graph_home,
        R.navigation.nav_graph_dashboard,
        R.navigation.nav_graph_notification
    )

    // Setup the bottom navigation view with a list of navigation graphs
    val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
        navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
        fragmentManager = childFragmentManager,
        containerId = R.id.nav_host_container,
        intent = requireActivity().intent
    )
```

You get error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find Navigator with name "include-dynamic". You must call NavController.addNavigator() for each navigation type.
```

If you change `NavHostFragment` with `DynamicNavHostFragment` in `obtainNavHostFragment` method

```
private fun obtainNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    fragmentTag: String,
    navGraphId: Int,
    containerId: Int
): DynamicNavHostFragment {
    // If the Nav Host fragment exists, return it
    val existingFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) as DynamicNavHostFragment?
    existingFragment?.let { return it }

    // Otherwise, create it and return it.
    val navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.create(navGraphId) as DynamicNavHostFragment
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(containerId, navHostFragment, fragmentTag)
        .commitNow()
    return navHostFragment
}
```

you get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment cannot be cast to androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.fragment.DynamicNavHostFragment
```

since `NavHostFragment.create()` returns `NavHostFragment` instead of type `extends` `NavHostFragment`

```
public static NavHostFragment create(@NavigationRes int graphResId) {
    return create(graphResId, null);
}
```

I asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627332/how-to-create-a-custom-fragment-that-extends-navhostfragment-with-its-own-back)

Is it possible to implement dynamic features with only `BottomNavigationView` with back stack for each tab?

Comment: What did you do in in the end? I have the same question

Comment: @Urmzd I answered it. You can check out the answer below or the [link](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Posts-MVVM-DaggerHilt-Dynamic-Feature-RxJava3-Flow-Sample) for working sample with bottom navigation and dynamic modules.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Posts-MVVM-DaggerHilt-Dynamic-Feature-RxJava3-Flow-Sample) is a working sample if you wish to check out, implementation in this answer is `MainFragmentBottomNav`. `MainFragment` uses `ViewPager2` to set BottomNavigation tabs.

This is a little bit like a workaround but it works.

Create a fragment that extends `DynamicNavHostFragment`.

```
/**
 * [DynamicNavHostFragment] creator class which
 * uses [BaseDynamicNavHostFragment.createDynamicNavHostFragment] function with navigation graph
 * parameter
 */
class BaseDynamicNavHostFragment : DynamicNavHostFragment() {

    private val navControllerViewModel by activityViewModels<NavControllerViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
//    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
//        val navResId = arguments?.get(KEY_GRAPH_ID) as Int
//        val startDestinationArgs = arguments?.get(KEY_START_DESTINATION_ARGS) as? Bundle
//
//        findNavController().setGraph(navResId, startDestinationArgs)
//    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Set this navController as ViewModel's navController
        navControllerViewModel.currentNavController.value = Event(navController)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        navControllerViewModel.currentNavController.value = Event(null)
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    companion object {

        private const val KEY_GRAPH_ID = "android-support-nav:fragment:graphId"
        private const val KEY_START_DESTINATION_ARGS =
            "android-support-nav:fragment:startDestinationArgs"

        /**
         * Create a new NavHostFragment instance with an inflated [NavGraph] resource.
         *
         * @param graphResId resource id of the navigation graph to inflate
         * @param startDestinationArgs arguments to send to the start destination of the graph
         * @return a new NavHostFragment instance
         */

        @JvmStatic
        fun createDynamicNavHostFragment(
            @NavigationRes graphResId: Int,
            startDestinationArgs: Bundle? = null
        ): BaseDynamicNavHostFragment {

            if (graphResId == 0) throw NavigationException("Navigation graph id cannot be 0")

            val bundle: Bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putInt(KEY_GRAPH_ID, graphResId)

                if (startDestinationArgs != null) {
                    putBundle(KEY_START_DESTINATION_ARGS, startDestinationArgs)
                }
            }

            return BaseDynamicNavHostFragment().apply {
                arguments = bundle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The constants below are mapped to values from `NavHostFragment`, i used the same values in `NavHostFragment` so when arguments are checked it would work like

```
`NavHostFragment.create()` which has a source code

public static NavHostFragment create(@NavigationRes int graphResId,
        @Nullable Bundle startDestinationArgs) {
    Bundle b = null;
    if (graphResId != 0) {
        b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(KEY_GRAPH_ID, graphResId);
    }
    if (startDestinationArgs != null) {
        if (b == null) {
            b = new Bundle();
        }
        b.putBundle(KEY_START_DESTINATION_ARGS, startDestinationArgs);
    }

    final NavHostFragment result = new NavHostFragment();
    if (b != null) {
        result.setArguments(b);
    }
    return result;
}
```

`BaseDynamicNavHostFragmen().createDynamicNavHostFragment()` function is identical as as NavHostFragment.create() but returns `DynamicNavHostFragment` instead of `NavHostFragment()`. You can also uncomment the lines and setGraph and check other conditions but using workaround for const values makes it simpler. The values of `KEY_GRAPH_ID`, and `KEY_START_DESTINATION_ARGS` match with NavHostFragment source code.

After that change one line in obtainNavHost function NavigationExtension.kt which is provided in question.

```
private fun obtainNavHostFragment(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    fragmentTag: String,
    navGraphId: Int,
    containerId: Int
): NavHostFragment {
    // If the Nav Host fragment exists, return it
    val existingFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) as NavHostFragment?
    existingFragment?.let { return it }

    // Otherwise, create it and return it.
    val navHostFragment = BaseDynamicNavHostFragment.createDynamicNavHostFragment(navGraphId)
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(containerId, navHostFragment, fragmentTag)
        .commitNow()
    return navHostFragment
}
```

the change is `BaseDynamicNavHostFragment.createDynamicNavHostFragment(navGraphId)`

Finally in app navigation folder create empty nav graphs which define start destinations as dynamic nav host fragment nav graphs with `<include-dynamic>`

for instance **nav_graph_dash_board_start.xml** in app module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_dashboard_start"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_graph_dashboard">

    <!-- Dashboard  dynamic feature module -->
    <include-dynamic
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_dashboard"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.dashboard"
        app:graphResName="nav_graph_dashboard"
        app:moduleName="dashboard">

    </include-dynamic>
</navigation>
```

And in dynamic feature module **nav_graph_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/nav_graph_dashboard"
    app:moduleName="dashboard"
    app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="Dashboard Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

</navigation>
```